Prove that the expansion of $a^x - 1 - x \log_e (a + x)$ as a power series in $x$, begins with a term in $x^2$
Prove that the expansion of $a^x - 1 - x \log_e (a + x)$ as a power series in $x$, begins with a term in $x^2$ and find the coefficient of this term.
I thought using Maclaurin series expansion, letting $f(x) = a^x - 1 - x \log_e (a + x)$
First derivative with respect to $x$:
$f'(x) = a^x(1 + \log_e(x)) - (\frac{x}{a + x} + \log_e (a + x))$
At this point I could see that substituting $x = 0$ can't work to find $f'(0)$, because $\log_e(0)$ is undefined.
Please point me in the right direction how best to expand $f(x) = a^x - 1 - x \log_e (a + x)$.
Thank you.

Note that $d(a^x)/dx = a^x\log_e(a)$, not "$a^x(1 + \log_e(x))$" so
$$f'(x) = a^x\log_e(a) - \left[\frac{x}{a + x} + \log_e (a + x)\right]$$
so
$$f'(0) = \log_e(a) - \log_e (a)= 0$$

Thank you for correcting me. Much appreciated!

Write $\ln := \log_e$. Then $a^x = e^{\ln(a^x)} = e^{x\ln(a)} = 1 + (x\ln(a)) + (x\ln(a))^2/2 + O(x^3) = 1 + \ln(a) \cdot x + \ln(a)^2/2 \cdot x^2 + O(x^2)$. Next, $\ln(a+x) = \ln(a) + \ln(1 + x/a) = \ln(a) + (x/a + O(x^2))$, hence $x\ln(a+x) = \ln(a)\cdot x + 1/a \cdot x^2 + O(x^3)$. Therefore
\begin{align}
a^x - 1 - x\ln(a + x) &= \left(1+ \ln(a)\cdot x + \frac{\ln(a)^2}{2} x^2\right) - 1 - \left( \ln(a)\cdot x + \frac{1}{a}x^2\right) + O(x^3) \\ 
&= \left(\frac{\ln(a)^2}{2} - \frac{1}{a}\right)x^2 + O(x^3).
\end{align}
If $\frac{\ln(a)^2}{2} - \frac{1}{a} = 0$, then $a\ln(a)^2 = 2$, whose solution is $a \approx 2.46$ (to 3 significant figures). So if $a\ln(a)^2 \neq 2$, then the Maclaurin Series of $a^x - 1 - x\ln(a + x)$ starts with the $x^2$ term. However, if $a\ln(a)^2 = 2$, then the Maclurin Series either starts with the $x^3$ term or later.

You could also show that the $x^n$ will be missing if $$(n-1) a^{n-1} \log ^n(a)=(-1)^n, n!$$ the solution of which being given in terms of Lambert function.

Thank you for your solution!

You are welcome, Nik.

Try to check for $a=1,2,3$ and so on.
$$f(x)=a^{x}-1-x\log_e(a+x)$$
$$\implies f(x)=a^{x}-1-x\ln(a+x)$$
Let $a=1$
Therefore $$f(x)=1^{x}-1-x\ln(1+x)$$
Now we all know that $1^{x}=1$ for any value of $x$.
Therefore $$f(x)=-x\ln(1+x)$$
Let's now use the series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$
Therefore, $$f(x)=-x\left(x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\frac{x^{4}}{4}+O(x^{5})\right)$$
Therefore we can easily say that for $a=1$ the series expansion of $f(x)$ starts with $x^{2}$.
Let's assume now for $a=2$.
Therefore, $$f(x)=2^{x}-1-x\ln(2+x)$$
Now $$2^{x}=1+x\ln(2)+\frac{(x\ln(2))^{2}}{2}+\frac{(x\ln(2))^{3}}{6}+O(x^{4})$$
Again, $$\ln(2+x)=\ln(2)+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^{2}}{8}+O(x^{3})$$
Therefore, $$f(x)=2^{x}-1-x\ln(2+x)$$
$$f(x)=x\ln(2)+\frac{(x\ln(2))^{2}}{2}+\frac{(x\ln(2))^{3}}{6}-x\left(\ln(2)+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^{2}}{8}\right)$$
Therefore the series expansion of $f(x)$ starts with $x^{2}$
Now try to prove for the actual function $f(x)=a^{x}-1-x\ln(a+x)$ without putting any values of $a$
Just use the power series expansions of $a^{x}$ and $\ln(a+x)$. For reference see the case of $a=2$.
Note :
$f(x)=\ln(2+x)$
$\implies f(0)=\ln(2)$
$\implies f'(x)=\frac{1}{2+x}$
$\implies f'(0)=\frac{1}{2}$
$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2+x}$
$\implies f''(x)=\frac{-1}{(2+x)^{2}}$
$\implies f''(0)=-\frac{1}{4}$
Therefore the power series expansion of $\ln(2+x)$ is
$\ln(2+x)=\ln(2)+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2!}\right)+O(x^{3})$

Many thanks for your insight!

Pls don't say like this. I always try to help others.
